# Pass JSON as one of the parameter through a Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to pass a JSON string to a node using a Jenkins Job.

```
JSON={"Automation":{"Env":"XXX","No of TCs to Run":"08","Suite":{"SAMPLE1":[{"testcases":"TC01,TC02,TC03,TC04"},{"TC_Username":"test@xxxxx.xom","TC_Password":"P!assword"},{"TS_Username":"test@xxxxx.xom","TS_Password":"AgeAS2"},{"TM_Username":"test@xxxxx.xom","TM_Password":"P!assword","TM_Company":"TEST","TM_FirstName":"Test","TM_LastName":"FARIZ"}]}} }
```

code in the Build Section of Jenkins jobs:

```
cd C:\Test
BatchRunner.bat %JSON%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any batch file passing of the arguments works like this -

**greet.bat** file -

```
@echo Hello %1
```

If you run this as

```
greet John
```

It will output

```
Hello John
```

For JSON objects as parameters don't forget to use a delimiter backward slash - `\` to escape double quotes - `"`

For example -

```
"{\"name\":\"abc\",\"place\":\"xyz\"}"
```

will be passed as -

```
{"name":"abc","place":"xyz"}`
```

Hope this helps.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-do-i-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file) and [this](http://www.itprotoday.com/windows-8/how-do-i-pass-parameters-batch-file) web page for more info.

Comment: Escaping the "" is the trick which i m working on now to resolve this.

Comment: I have updated my Sample with the actual one, im not able to escape the chars for this.

Answer (score 1):

I did this by using "This project is parameterized" Option present in Jenkins- General Section.

Include a Multi-line string Parameter where you can pass the JSON as parameter. Include the code in the BUILD section as below:

*Note: Make sure the String is valid as you need to enclose them in a double quote.*

```
cd C:\Test
BatchRunner.bat %JSON%
```