# Pinger batch file request

Tags: batch-file

This is the command I need:

```
ping oldschool"world#".runescape.com
```

I want to be able to open the batch file, type in `world#`, and have it fill in and type that command.

e.g.

```
ping oldschool53.runescape.com
```

Any help or direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass command line parameters to a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-do-i-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 0):

Add a batch file called pw.bat with this content:

```
ping oldschool%1.runescape.com
```

I you type "pw 12" it will ping world #12.

If you want it to be reachable from anywhere in you command prompt, put the file in a foler which is added to the PATH variable, you can see them if you type PATH in your command prompt.

Comment: not quite correct. Check again, how a parameter is referenced (`call /?`)

Comment: ...it should be `%1` not `%1%`.

Comment: Thanks guys! I was lost but figured out you have to put the pw.bat in the cmd.exe file location, then type "pw world#" in cmd (for any other noobs out there).

Comment: Why not using `set /p`?

Comment: @moosepp - You can call batch scripts from anywhere on your computer; it doesn't have to be in the same directory as `cmd.exe`.