# How can use .bat file or should I use other automation for this?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have mp4 files that I want to run an ffmpeg command on, where the command is formatted like this:

```
ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.8*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=1.25[a] " -map "[v]" -map "[a]" faster.mp4
```

How can I either define a function or something to make this simpler, for example in Python logic I would've done something like this

```
def speed_up(ogvideo, newvidname):
     ffmpeg -i ogvideo -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.8*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=1.25[a] " -map "[v]" -map "[a]" newvidname
```

Can I do this with a .bat file to then drag and drop videos onto it? Can i define a command in my CMD interface so I can just type:

```
speed_up(video.mp4, newvid.mp4)
```

Any ideas are welcome
Thanks

Comment: yes, for a bat file with parameters take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-a-batch-file  you can basically access the first and second parameter with `%1` and `%2`, then you call it like `./myBatchFile.bat Parameter1 Parameter2` from the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a batch file named `converter.bat` and put it in the same folder where you have your video.

Notice I have changed the input and output filenames with `%1` and `%2` which refer to the first and second parameters passed to the bat file.

Content of `converter.bat`:

```
ffmpeg -i %1 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.8*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=1.25[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" %2
```

Then from the console call it with:

```
.\converter.bat video.mp4 faster.mp4
```